# How to backup Android SDK?

Tags: android

I have downloaded and installed `android-sdk-windows`. Now I am planning for a reinstall of my Windows as the current ones seems to have got corrupted because of virus. Can someone tell me how to backup the `android-sdk` so that I dont have to redownload all the sources once again.

Comment: If you are going to reinstall Windows, Eclipse, browser, plus probably a metric crapton of other things, the SDKs are not a big deal. If they are, try a memory stick and copypasta.

Comment: @Miss Noob you can save it in any directory, after reinstalling windown you just need to give path to eclipse, it will work. And I hope you remember me...I hope so really

Comment: Sorry I don't think this really has anything to do with coding and will probably be closed. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Jack It's about tools used directly for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Attach an external hard drive/pen drive to your computer via a [USB
  port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)
- Copy the folder where you installed android-sdk-windows (select the
  folder then press Ctrl+C)
- Open the hard drive once it is connected by double clicking on it.
- Press Ctrl+V once you are inside the hard drive folder.

Comment: just say that I can reuse it by copy pasting it and No need of re-install.

Comment: yup no need to reinstall :)

Comment: @MissNoob You just have to give the path of sdk from preferences in eclipse. So, a normal copy of sdk is good to reuse again.